# If $f(z) = u +iv$ is a complex function such that $u$ and $v$ are both harmonic, is $f(z)$ necessarily analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that all harmonic functions arise as the real parts of analytic; however I am not sure what the correct answer to the question is. I think that if $u$ and $v$ are harmonic then it has to be analytic since an analytic function is one that we can take the derivative of and differentiate. In order to verify if a function is harmonic or not, we have to take the second partial derivative of $u$ and $v$ which can only be done if a function is continuous. Is my thought process correct or do I have any holes/mistakes in my thought process and answer?

Comment: The real part of $z$ is a harmonic function of $z$ (because the identity function is analytic); $0$ is also a harmonic function of $z$ (because the constant zero function is analytic), but Re$(z)+i0$ is not analytic.

Comment: "I know that all harmonic functions arise as the real parts of analytic" That's not true except locally.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $u(x,y) = x$ is harmonic. Is $x+ix$ analytic?

Comment: $x+ix$ is harmonic; it is not analytic.

Comment: Right, fixed typo, thanks.

Comment: Well, now I get it.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

No, $v$ has to be the *harmonic conjugate* of $u$, that is $u$ and $v$
have to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.$$
If $u$ is harmonic, there's always a solution of these for $v$ locally,
that is in the neighbourhood of any given point.

Comment: So basically a complex function f(z) = u + iv can be harmonic but not analytic because there is a possiblity that one of the first order partials used to verify whether or not the function is analytic does not satisfy this condition. WHy is that? I am still a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a few things:
1)If a function is analytic, it can be (locally) written as a power series.

2)A function is harmonic given $\Delta u=0$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator.

3)A complex function is holomorphic (or analytic) if it statisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Eq and is totally differentiable as a real function (from and onto $\mathbb{R}^2$). That implies that the real and imaginary part of $f(z)$ have to be at least differentiable once.

However, those things imply a few things:
Any real harmonic function is analytic.
The real and imaginary part of a complex, holomorphic (or analytical) function are harmonic.
For a complex valued function, analytic and holomorphic are the same.

Comment: Thank you; we've just now started discussing complex functions in class; we haven't talked about the Laplace operator or power series, yet